# Year selector for jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am developing an app for blackberry(6,7,10) in jquery mobile.

I need a date picker as well as an year selector. For the datepicker I have used the jqmobile default datepicker option .Here is the url  to it. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

I don't know how to make an Year selector. Can someone help?

Comment: show some code what you have so far

Comment: @DavidChase I have used the same datepicker as detailed in the above url and it is fine for choosing day,month and year.What I need is a year picker

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided it is also possible to just "forward" a year so that suits your needs?

Anyway:

You can also look into the possibilities by using a third-party solution. I'm using [mobiscroll](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/datetime) and thatone has a nice datetime scoller (you can only use the 'year" wheel if you want) and there is also a calendar available.

Comment: How does the linked example allow you to go forward by year?

Comment: @Matthijs I want a selector with YEAR selection alone.Day,month options should not be provided in display.Is there any plugin in jqmobile for it which works on BB device.Will mobiscroll be helpful?

Comment: I decided to use jquery mobile dropdown.